# LinkedIn JS API token exchange to REST token using Spring Social for Linkedin

Tags: spring, algorithm, debugging, rest, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to do the following:

Let the user authenticate and authorize through Linkedin using Linkedin JSAPI, then take the authentication details and send them to my server to get the user profile via server side communication.

I got the Linkedin button setup, got the authorization cookie all the way to my server (as described [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens)), and was able to verify that the token is indeed signed correctly with my secret key.

Now I'm stuck at the point where I am supposed to take the token I got from JSAPI and exchange it for an access token.

This is the code I'm using, as mentioned it uses Spring Social for Linkedin, and it doesn't work as it throws a 401 Unauthorized response:

```
    LinkedInConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
            new LinkedInConnectionFactory(myLinkedinId, myLinkedinSecret);
    OAuth1Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
    AuthorizedRequestToken art = new AuthorizedRequestToken(new OAuthToken(codeIGotFromJSAPI, aSecretKey), whereDoIGetThisSignature);
    OAuthToken accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccessToken(art, null);
    if (accessGrant == null) return null;
    Connection<LinkedIn> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
    if (connection != null) {
        LinkedIn linkedin = connection.getApi();
        return linkedin.profileOperations().getUserProfile();
    }
```

What I'm actually confused about is the AuthorizedRequestToken object.  The `codeIGotFromJSAPI` part is simple enough I think, it's just access_token, but what about `aSecretKey`, is it just my linkedin secret key? what about whereDoIGetThisSignature, how do I create that one?  Do I use the same hash method as I used to validate the linkedin response and hash the access_token with my secret linkedin key?  In the linkedin page, it says:

> You need to pass four values as query parameters:
>
> 1. oauth_consumer_key, to identify yourself
> 2. xoauth_oauth2_access_token parameter, set to the value of the access_token field in the cookie.
> 3. signature_method set to HMAC-SHA1
> 4. signature, calculated as described in the OAuth 1.0a spec

So (1) is automatically done by the connection I suppose, (2) is the access token I provided, but how do I do (3) and (4)?

Lets suppose I get the following data in the JSAPI cookie set by Linkedin:

```
{
 "signature_method":"HMAC-SHA1",
 "signature_order": ["access_token", "member_id"],
 "access_token":"AD2dpVe1tOclAsNYsCri4nOatfstw7ZnMzWP",
 "signature":"73f948524c6d1c07b5c554f6fc62d824eac68fee",
 "member_id":"vvUNSej47H"
 "signature_version": 1
}
```

What do I need to do with it to go through the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Read the cookie
- Transform `"signature":"..."` to `&signature=...`
- Transform `"signature_method":"HMAC-SHA1"` to `&signature_method=HMAC-SHA1`
- Transform `"member_id":"..."` to `&oauth_customer_key=...`
- Transform `"access_token":"..."` to `&xoauth_oauth2_access_token=...`
- Append all to the LinkedIn url plus `?`

Comment: As of now **member_id** is not listed as a required parameter in the description of this process but oauth_consumer_key, xoauth_oauth2_access_token, signature_method and signature [LinkedIn.com: Exchange JSAPI Tokens for REST API OAuth Tokens](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens)

Comment: @Christoph Yes. On the right column are &signature, &signature_method, &oauth_customer_key, &xoauth_oauth2_access_token. The left column is the code in question. Sorry it's not formatted for readability.

Comment: But also oauth_customer_key is not listed, or? When looking into their example code member_id is not referenced and oauth_customer_key is not mentioned. Sorry, I don't see it :(

Comment: @Christoph In the question, `"member_id":"vvUNSej47H"` is part of the JSAPI response. `oauth_customer_key` is mentioned in both the answer as well as the hyperlinked document. Thanks.

Comment: oauth_customer_key is not listed in the hyperlinked document, but oauth_consumer_key is, that's a difference. Do you agree? And oauth_consumer_key is documented as identifier for the app ("yourself"). Member_id is indeed mentioned in both but it is not mentioned in section 3 of this hyperlinked document which describes how the exchange has to be executed. Your arguing is not convincing, sorry. What do I overlook?

Comment: @Christoph Thanks. The noun `customer` was mistyped instead of `consumer`. The noun `member_id` is preceded by the verb `Transform`, which means it does not need to be mentioned in section 3 of this hyperlinked document.

Comment: Paul, I know that you are saying, that one should set the query parameter `oauth_customer_key` to the value of `member_id` (i.e. `Transform`) but I wonder why? I wonder because this offical documentaton (it is official, do you agree?) is at least saying something contradictory in section 3. And because it is an official documentation it is really important that it is written there. Otherwise you need to say that this official documentation is wrong or at least incomplete or unclear. That's reason why I am asking ;)

Comment: @Christoph Yes, the `oauth_consumer_key` is the API key generated at registration, not the `member_id`. That will be corrected shortly. The forum discussion is not canonical, nor easy to find, that is why this question exists. The underlying issue is poor documentation combined with poor SEO.

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedIn JSAPI Token Exchange as described in [Exchange JSAPI Tokens for REST API OAuth Tokens](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens) is currently not supported by Spring Social, according to a [Spring forum discussion](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/127876-linkedin-js-api-token-exchange-to-rest-token-using-spring-social-for-linkedin) on this topic.

But there are implementation available to solve this task without Spring Social by using standard OAuth libraries available for Java. The LinkedIn user's access token, that you get from the exchange, can be put into a new `AccessGrant` object which can be used to create a Spring Social `Connection<?>` in the user's `ConnectionRepository`.

The code published in the [LinkedIn developer forum discussion](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/exchanging-jsapi-token-rest-api-oauth-token-java) shows how to use [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) to perform the exchange. The request that has to be sent to LinkedIn is a standard OAuth request but must ship the `access_token` field from the JSAPI token object as a HTTP query parameter `xoauth_oauth2_access_token`. The `member_id` that is also available to you is just for your information, and the `signature` allows you to verify both `access_token` and `member_id` without querying LinkedIn.